# Including Bootstrap Classes with js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

As exercise, I'm creating a simple quiz app without using jQuery. I'm trying to add radio buttons as answer options using javascript

html body as follows

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <p id="question"></p>
        <form name="answers">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check" id="answersId">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

my js script below would add radio buttons within `div class="form-check"`

```
function firstQuestion() {

        var answerSection = document.getElementById("answersId");

        for(var i = 0; i < allQuestions[0].choices.length; i++) {
            var radioElement = [];
            radioElement[i] = document.createElement("input");
            radioElement[i].setAttribute("class", "form-check-input");
            radioElement[i].setAttribute("type", "radio");
            radioElement[i].setAttribute("name", "choice");
            radioElement[i].setAttribute("value", i);

            var label = [];
            label[i] = document.createElement("label");
            label[i].setAttribute("class", "form-check-label");

            var labelText = [];
            labelText[i] = document.createTextNode(allQuestions[0].choices[i]);

            label[i].appendChild(radioElement[i]);

            label[i].appendChild(labelText[i]);

            answerSection.appendChild(label[i]);
        };
    }
```

I'm not able to get the bootstrap appearance, i.e.:

-each radio button is inline, rather than in a new line (arranged vertically)

-spacing between the button and label is not like bootstrap example

Why is this so? Could someone point out to me?

Answer (score 0):

thats because bootstrap relies on jquery, you can't expect bootstrap to work without jquery

Answer (score 0):

```js
var answerSection = document.getElementById("answersId");
var radioElement = [];
var label = [];
var labelText = [];
var span;
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  span = document.createElement("span");
  span.setAttribute("style", "padding:15px");
  radioElement[i] = document.createElement("input");
  radioElement[i].setAttribute("class", "form-check-input");
  radioElement[i].setAttribute("type", "radio");
  radioElement[i].setAttribute("name", "choice");
  radioElement[i].setAttribute("value", i);
  label[i] = document.createElement("label");
  label[i].setAttribute("class", "form-check-label");
  labelText[i] = document.createTextNode("choice " + i);
  label[i].appendChild(radioElement[i]);
  label[i].appendChild(labelText[i]);
  span.appendChild(label[i]);

  answerSection.appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <p id="question"></p>
    <form name="answers">
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check" id="answersId">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should add these 3 lines to make bootstrap work. These are the CDN links, but if you have these on your computer then add them properly

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And as said by @leccionesonline bootstrap.min.js requires jquery.min.js file. Hence you should load jquery.min.js before bootstrap.min.js

Here is refrence [link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp)

Comment: this has already been added. Other bootstrap formatting works.

I found another clue, however. When I type in html directly (rather than using js to add the radio choices, there is a space added before label text if i look into browser->elements).

If i use js document.createTextNode, that space is not there.

Comment: You can add your code to jsfiddle, which can make the question more clear..

Comment: check the updated post.. and mark and upvote if useful. Happy coding

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uw6181fc/

you can refer to jsfiddle above. there's almost no spacing between the radio button and the label text. (could this be a consequence of using js document.createElement rather than coding html directly?)

Comment: check my code, I have added padding which will give you the space between radio buttons as required. There will be no spacing unless you add . Also if you write `<label>` inside `<p>` or `<div>` it will go to the next line by **Default**. If you use `<span>` you get it on the same line by **Default**.